# Stop/deactivate current OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi

How to deactivate current bundle if in its activate method is thrown particular exception?

```
    public void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) {
        try{
             if(something) throw new Exception(); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
             //deactivate bundle... 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're talking about Declarative Service components, in that case, you can just let the activate method throw an exception (perhaps wrapping it inside a runtime exception), in that case the component won't be activated.

You should realize that the DS runtime might try to activate it more than once, though.

There is a pretty similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897947/how-do-i-fail-in-my-declarative-services-activator)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247120/osgi-background-thread-failure), particularly the answer and comments by Peter Kriens. Bundles should not try to stop themselves. If a bundle encounters an error, it should log it to the LogService. But as Frank says, if this is a DS component then simply throwing the exception is best because then the DS runtime will log it to LogService for you.

Comment: No need to wrap the exception, you can throw any exception from the DS methods.